# Use Azure Function Binding to return list of Blobs in a Container

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the purpose of Azure Function Input Bindings. But I want to be able to return the list of blobs in a container on a HttpTrigger using a blob input binding.
Is this possible or do I need to access the Blob Storage API directly from the Function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible, blob binding is to read single blob once according to specified blob path. If we work with c#, we can use `CloudBlobContainer` as [input binding type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input---usage) just for convenience. Otherwise we have to leverage Storage SDK to access Blob Service.

Comment: how do we iterate thorugh a number of blobs inside of a container?